# Background Center Problems

Tags: css, html, background, center

This is my website coding and I am already running into problems, please help!

This is my CSS style sheet:

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

body
{
  background-color: #45a8e1;
  background-image:url('images/background.png');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

And then here is the HTML:

```
<body>

  <div id="header" class="center">
    <img src="images/header.png">
  </div>

</body>
```

The final results are coming okay but the page is extremely wide. I am trying to fit my background image in the view-port (page). Also, I want to center my div in the center which doesn't seem to be working since the page is so wide.

Comment: can you show `image` of what you are trying to achieve it is very difficult for us to picture out what your are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this css:

```
.center {
   display:inline-block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

body
{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #45a8e1;
  background:url('images/background.png');
  -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
  -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
  -o-background-size: auto 100%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Note: `background-size` is not supported in IE8 and below.

Comment: Still formatting my background-image to be very big, I used the single row tool in Photoshop which took only 1 pixel wide and then ~800 pixels tall. That is the image I am using to save loading times.

Comment: Try the `background-size: auto 100%;`. See my updated answer.

Comment: That makes it vertically correct in size, but the horizontal still has a large scroll bar of about 2000 pixels when it shouldn't have any scroll bar and just load the centered header in the middle.

Comment: I have figured out the problem... The image was not cropped correctly and it had a huge transparent border! Thanks for the help everyone, sorry for waste of time it is late and I am very new to coding... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/QJWxF/)

```
#header {
    background: url('/*yourImageHere*/') repeat-x center;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to repeat my header image?

Comment: @psychoticpanda if so just change `repeat-x` to `no-repeat`